# Using an Int in the if condition

Tags: c, if-statement

In my current class I am seeing a lot of times where my teacher puts a number as the condition of an if statement then asks for the output. I'm confused as to how these statements are being evaluated.
Example:

```
if(-1) {
   x = 35;
}
```

or

```
if(0) {
   x = 35;
}
```

Why does it go inside the if statement instead of just ignoring it? What is making `if(-1)` evaluate true? And why does `if(0)` evaluate false?

This is an online class so I can't get help directly from the teacher usually. I have searched for a few hours on various websites about C for loops, but I haven't found anything relevant yet to my question.

Comment: `0` stands for *false*, all other integers (e.g. `-1`) values stand for *true*

Comment: The question is different but the answer does seem to answer my question. Any non-zero number evaluates true in C, is that correct? @mkrieger1

Comment: As to "why does it do inside ... instead of just ignoring it?".  Purely for educational purposes.   The compiler will almost treat `if(-1) { x = 35; }` exactly the same as `x = 35`, and will completely remove `if(0) { x = 35; }`.

Comment: Interesting tidbit: the expression `a > b` has a value of type `int`. That value is either `0` or `1` ... so `if (a > b)` is ultimately executed as either `if (0)` or `if (1)`

Comment: @pmg It looks like the only operator that will result in `bool` type is the cast `(bool)` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't have a "real" boolean type. When evaluating integers, `0` is a "false", and anything else is a "true" value.

Comment: Well, I find this statement somewhat misleading. C does have a "real" `bool` type, and it can be proven: https://ideone.com/t6RTk0